# Does prior-CPU-usage-time dependent scheduling algorithm exist in Operating System?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I'd like to know if there is scheduling algorithm something like, priority of certain process getting higher if prior-CPU-usage-time is small. It is similar with Weighted Round Robin algorithm, but its priority depends on 'prior-CPU-usage-time'. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen applications that adjusted priority in the manner you describe. Their usual effect, however, is to muck up system response. The old DECUS tapes were full of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at multilevel feedback/rr scheduling of the old UNIXs, e.g. 3.xBSD. There, you have aging in dependence of the cup usage.